# Angular-google-maps call after $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I need to show a map with [angular-google-maps plugin](http://angular-google-maps.org) with coordinates from a db after an $http call (with promise).

This is the directive in my template:

```
<google-map center="map.center" draggable="true" refresh="true" control="map.control" data-tap-disabled="true" zoom="map.zoom">
    <marker coords="marker.coords" options="marker.options" idkey="marker.id" ></marker>
  </google-map>
```

This is the controller which handles the show of the map

```
.controller('FriendDetailCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $ionicLoading, $ionicPopup, Friends) {
$ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<i class="icon ion-loading-a"></i><br>Lade Details...',
    noBackdrop: true
});


// Detail Informationen holen
$scope.detail = {};
Friends.getDetail($stateParams.friendId).then(function(b) {
    $scope.detail = b;

    // Karte
    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 30,
            longitude: -40
        },
        zoom: 12
    };


    // Marker
    $scope.marker = {
        id: 0,
        coords: {
            latitude: $scope.detail.lat,
            longitude: $scope.detail.long
        },
        options: {
            draggable: false
        }
    }


    $ionicLoading.hide();
});
```

The Service who returns the data:

```
getDetail: function(friendId) {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            promise2 = $http({
                url: "http://dev.tellthedj.de/db/getGutschein.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {"gutscheinId":friendId}
            }).then(function(response2) {
                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return response2.data;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise2;
        }
```

the data from the promise, like id, name etc. is shown perfectly. Also the coordinates coming from the database. I inserted to test only integers to the coordinates. If I place the $scope.map call before the Friends.getDetail() the map works. But the call is returning a promise. Could you help? THX

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: unfortunately not :( the cdn of that angular-google-maps is down right now. Got the plugin locally. I will do a fiddle if the plugin is up again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this situation, call the `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` as part of one of your `.then` functions
*after* your `$http` promise returns.

Here's an example which uses the browser `navigator.geolocation` to get the user's current location - it can take anywhere up to a few seconds (more if user authorisation is required) so it's generally slower than an `$http` call.

I've wrapped the `getCurrentLocation()` service in a $q promise so that the controller waits until the current location is returned before loading the map. (see code in fiddle)

The same method would work for your $http call.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi, myAppServices) {
    $scope.myCurrentLocation = {};

    myAppServices.getCurrentLocation()
    .then(function(myCurrentLocation){
        $scope.myCurrentLocation = myCurrentLocation;
    })
    .then(function(){return uiGmapGoogleMapApi})    // map load call is here
    .then(function(maps){
        $scope.map = {
            center: {        // set on San Francisco as initial default
                latitude: 37.7749295, 
                longitude: -122.4194155 
            },
            zoom: 13,
            pan: 1,
            options: myAppServices.getMapOptions().mapOptions,
        };
        $scope.map.center = $scope.myCurrentLocation
    })
});
```

You can check out the rest of the code in the jsfiddle.

### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/er1xp42h/)

Notes:
- I've defined the `$scope.myCurrentLocation = myCurrentLocation;` in it's own 'promise' (for clarity), even though it isn't really a promise - but you can equally put any synchronous task in the same promise function as the `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` (as shown below) - just make sure you put them before, and that you `return` the `uiGmapGoogleMapApi` or you won't have access to the `maps` object the promise returns:

```
myAppServices.getCurrentLocation()
.then(function(myCurrentLocation){
    $scope.myCurrentLocation = myCurrentLocation;
    return uiGmapGoogleMapApi})            // this is where the map load call is made
.then(function(maps){...
```

-  I've put the `$scope.map.options` in a service also just to keep the controller neat and readable
- if you want to define `map.options` in the controller you'll have to do this within the last `.then` promise (ie after the map load) or you'll get `'google' is undefined` type errors for definitions like `mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` since any definitions will be [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), and the controller has no idea what `google` is until after the map is loaded

Comment: This deserves a +10. The fiddle has all you need to know to get W3C geolocation working with angular-google-maps